# Why does the Maven goal "package" include the resources in the jar, but the goal "jar:jar" doesn't?

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, maven-plugin

when I package my project with the Maven goal "package", the resources are included as well. They are originally located in the directory "src/main/resources".
Because I want to create an executable jar and add the classpath to the manifest, I'm using maven-jar-plugin.

I've configured it as the following likes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>at.program.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Why won't the jar file created with "jar:jar" include my resources as well. As far as I'm concerned it should use the same directories as the "package" goal (which are in my case inherited from the Maven Super POM).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`jar:jar`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) **goal** of the [Maven JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) is used to "*build a JAR from the current project*" and does only one thing: it packages the content of `target/classes` into a JAR in the `target` directory, and that's all. So, when you run `mvn jar:jar`, the plugin configuration in your pom **is** used, but `jar:jar` won't do more things than what I mentioned. If `target/classes` is empty or doesn't exist, no classes or resources will be packaged in the resulting JAR.

The `package` **phase** is a [build lifecycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and when you invoke `mvn package`, **all phases before** `package` will be executed (`process-resources`, `compile`, `process-test-resources`, etc) and will trigger the plugin goals [bound to these phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). So, for a project with a `<packaging>` of type `jar`, `jar:jar` is bound to `package` and will be run during the `package` phase but prior to that, the goals bound to phases preceding `package` will be triggered, including the one that copies the resources into `target/classes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [maven.jar.includes](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/jar/properties.html) in you jar plugin configuration.

Comment: This is for Maven 1, this question is about Maven 2.

Answer (score 0):

As I've found out, the maven-jar-plugin binds itself automatically to the package goal when the project packaging is set to "jar". So the "package" goal does everything that I want, including appending the classpath to the manifest and setting a main class.